# How to stop Windows 10 on a Surface tablet from dimming the screen when turning the tablet from sleep mode?

Tags: windows-10, brightness

How to stop Windows 10 on a Surface tablet from dimming the screen when turning the tablet from sleep mode?

I have the adjust brightness automatically.. checkbox under system -> Display turned off.
I am using the Win 10 Brightness Slider app to adjust the brightness. Maybe there's an app that keeps the brightness level sticky?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the amount of problems involving display brightness and windows 10, this utility has been found to fix the majority.

Twinkletray can be downloaded below and replaces your current brightness controls from the taskbar, and resume your set brightness on wake-up.

https://twinkletray.com